# A HTML link redirects to correct URL but page doesn't load and shows 403 error. The page loads fine once the page is refreshed

Tags: html, xampp, tomcat8, http-status-code-403

I have a web application hosted on Apache Tomcat which is installed on XAMPP (XAMPP is an app. like citrix/vmware). On clicking a particular link on the homepage, among many others that work absolutely fine, I'll be redirected to the required URL but the page doesn't load and shows 403 error. However, the page loads fine once the page is refreshed. Also, this error happens only when accessed from XAMPP(where it is hosted; using 'localhost'). This error does not occur when accessed outside XAMPP(using application url). All other links on the homepage works fine in both the cases

[ScreenShot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8pAw.png)

Can someone help fix this, please? Any support is much appreciated.

Comment: The message is self expanatory. The server cannot check the referrer of the petition and throws a forbidden exception (http 403). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: @bradbury9 The error occurs only for one particular link while every other link page work absolutely which are running on the very server/platform on which this particular one is residing. Also, this occurs only within this environment, only for this link and everything works well and good outside the xampp.